# A C language function is not listed in VS Code Workspace Symbols list (Ctrl+T)

Tags: visual-studio-code

A C language function having the definition below is not listed in VS Code symbols list. (Ctrl + T)

```
void funcA(void)
{
#if TEST
    if (var1 >= var2) {
        var3 = 1;
#else
    if (var4 >= var5) {
        var3 = 1;
#endif
    } else if (var5 >= var6) {
        var3 = 1;
    }
}
```

But the function is getting listed when the definition is changed like below.

```
void funcA(void)
{
#if TEST
    if (var1 >= var2) {
        var3 = 1;
        } else
#else
    if (var4 >= var5) {
        var3 = 1;
        } else
#endif
    if (var5 >= var6) {
        var3 = 1;
    }
}
```

This behaviour is the same irrespective of whether the macro `TEST` is defined or not.

How can I fix this problem in VS Code without changing the function definition?

Can this problem be fixed by updating any configuration/settings?